# Detached Head in GitHub

Tags: github, git-detached-head

Can someone help me?  I tried to sync to a branch of my GitHub project when it told me that I had a detached head.  How do I fix it?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are no longer on a branch

Try:

```
git branch myBranch
git checkout myBranch
```

And that should get you back to where you want to be.

Or you could checkout the branch you thought you were on

```
git checkout myBranchThatIThoughtIWasOn
```